# Why does chroot get ENOENT on an existing file?

Tags: linux, chroot, dynamic-linking, exec, elf

;TL-DR - **Answer:** because the dynamic linker ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 was missing.

I have mounted a squashfs (shouldn't matter) filesystem `-ro,loop` at `/mnt/foo`.

It contains among other things the following (`/mnt/foo` is the mount point):

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root    root     110088 jan 17  2013 /mnt/foo/bin/ls
-rw-r--r-- 1 root    root       5212 jul 23 09:35 /mnt/foo/etc/ld.so.cache
-rw-r--r-- 1 root    root          5 jul 23 09:35 /mnt/foo/etc/ld.so.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root    root      31168 maj 23  2013 /mnt/foo/lib/libacl.so.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root    root      18624 maj 20  2013 /mnt/foo/lib/libattr.so.1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root    root    1853400 okt 12  2013 /mnt/foo/lib/libc.so.6
-rw-r--r-- 1 root    root      14664 okt 12  2013 /mnt/foo/lib/libdl.so.2
-rw-r--r-- 1 root    root     256224 mar 11  2013 /mnt/foo/lib/libpcre.so.3
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root    root     135757 okt 12  2013 /mnt/foo/lib/libpthread.so.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root    root      31760 okt 12  2013 /mnt/foo/lib/librt.so.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root    root     134224 maj 23  2013 /mnt/foo/lib/libselinux.so.1
```

`/mnt/foo/etc/ld.so.conf` contains a single row (including newline) with just `/lib` on it.

Before creating the file system, I ran `ldconfig -r ${TOPDIR}` where `${TOPDIR}` resolved to the place that is now mounted at `/mnt/foo`.
A `strings` on `/mnt/foo/etc/ld.so.cache` shows it contains strings like `/lib/libpcre.so.3` and so on, so I don't think it is a problem with the shared libraries.

I figure it must be something silly I'm overlooking, but **I cannot figure out myself why a simple `chroot /mnt/foo /bin/ls` doesn't work.**

`readelf -d /mnt/foo/bin/ls | grep NEEDED` shows these libraries as needed:

```
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libselinux.so.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [librt.so.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libacl.so.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
```

Finally, `strace` shows this:

```
chroot("/mnt/foo")                      = 0
chdir("/")                              = 0
execve("/bin/ls", ["/bin/ls"], [/* 32 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

**This is the full strace chroot:**

```
# strace -f chroot /mnt/foo /bin/ls
execve("/usr/sbin/chroot", ["chroot", "/mnt/foo", "/bin/ls"], [/* 32 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x1985000
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fc115ac8000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=96457, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 96457, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fc115ab0000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\360\36\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1853400, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3961912, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fc1154e0000
mprotect(0x7fc11569d000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fc11589d000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1bd000) = 0x7fc11589d000
mmap(0x7fc1158a3000, 17464, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fc1158a3000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fc115aaf000
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fc115aad000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7fc115aad740) = 0
mprotect(0x7fc11589d000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x606000, 4096, PROT_READ)     = 0
mprotect(0x7fc115aca000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7fc115ab0000, 96457)           = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x1985000
brk(0x19a6000)                          = 0x19a6000
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=8463952, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 8463952, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fc114ccd000
close(3)                                = 0
chroot("/mnt/foo")                      = 0
chdir("/")                              = 0
execve("/bin/ls", ["/bin/ls"], [/* 32 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/locale.alias", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/charset.alias", O_RDONLY|O_NOFOLLOW) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(2, "chroot: ", 8chroot: )                 = 8
write(2, "failed to run command \342\200\230/bin/ls"..., 35failed to run command ‘/bin/ls’) = 35
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(2, ": No such file or directory", 27: No such file or directory) = 27
write(2, "\n", 1
)                       = 1
close(1)                                = 0
close(2)                                = 0
exit_group(127)                         = ?
+++ exited with 127 +++
```

So, is this `ENOENT` misleading?

**YES - ENOENT is a bit misleading. To me it has always meant "file not found".**

When the dynamic linker cannot be found, execve() gets ENOENT.

When the booting kernel tries to load `init` (or linuxrc or whatever), the error I get is "**Failed to execute /linuxrc (error -2).  Attempting defaults...**".

The problem happened due to a bug in my script that created this initial ramdisk. (it omitted libraries not pointed out by "=>" by `ldd`).

Two bonus questions to ponder for extra credits:

- what is `linux-vdso.so.1` that `ldd` shows without a path?
- why does `ldd` show ld-linux.so without a "`=>`"?

Comment: What about the dynamic linker itself (ld-linux.so or other)? Do an ldd to see what ls needs

Comment: so true, @StéphaneChazelas. It appears that I'm missing `ld-linux`!

Comment: Can you add `strace -s 1024` to get the full message of `strace`.

Comment: `-s 1024` only shows more of the libc.so.6 contents.

Comment: @MattBianco: so `-s 0`? some lines like `execve("/bin/ls", ["/bin/ls"], [/* 32 vars */])` is not printed enough.

Comment: @Gnouc That's just environment vars. The option is `-v` to show them (and other details) in linux strace. (`-e` on solaris `truss`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is `/bin/ls` don't just need the shared libraries, which you provided. It also needs the program that loads them; the linux loader.

To solve your problem you can copy the loader from your system (usually `/lib/ld-linux.so.2`) to the location of your chroot (`/mnt/foo/lib/ld-linux.so.2`).

Comment: Yes. Adding `/mnt/foo/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` solved it.