# How can I get ng e2e to run under Alpine: it currently returns E/launcher - Error: spawn <location> 5 ENOENT

Tags: docker, chrome, alpine-linux, podman

I'm running `npx ng e2e` from a docker CI environment under GitLab,. When I run it I get totally mundane setup/installation of chrome/webdriver..

```
[19:57:28] I/file_manager - creating folder /builds/cpanel/cpanel/demo-app/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium
[19:57:28] I/config_source - curl -o/builds/cpanel/cpanel/demo-app/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chrome-response.xml https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/
[19:57:29] I/downloader - curl -o/builds/cpanel/cpanel/demo-app/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_96.0.4664.45.zip https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/96.0.4664.45/chromedriver_linux64.zip
[19:57:30] I/update - chromedriver: unzipping chromedriver_96.0.4664.45.zip
[19:57:31] I/update - chromedriver: setting permissions to 0755 for /builds/cpanel/cpanel/demo-app/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_96.0.4664.45
Compiling @angular/core : es2015 as esm2015
... lots more compiling stuff..
```

Followed by failure to execute it,

```
[19:58:07] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[19:58:07] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
[19:58:07] E/launcher - spawn /builds/cpanel/cpanel/demo-app/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_96.0.4664.45 ENOENT
[19:58:07] E/launcher - Error: spawn /builds/cpanel/cpanel/demo-app/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_96.0.4664.45 ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:282:19)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:475:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
[19:58:07] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
```

Why would I be getting,

> E/launcher - Error: spawn /builds/cpanel/cpanel/demo-app/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_96.0.4664.45 ENOENT

When I can clearly see that chrome is unzipped there

---

I've tried putting editing `./e2e/protractor.conf.js` with different forms of

```js
chromeOptions: {
  binary: process.env.CHROME_BIN,
  args: ['--no-sandbox', '--headless', '--disable-gpu']
}
```

but nothing new happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jumping into the container I was able to confirm the file existed, but that I could not run it,

```
# ./chromedriver_96.0.4664.45
/bin/sh: ./chromedriver_96.0.4664.45: not found
```

I could confirm it was `+x`, when I run `file` on it it said,

> chromedriver_96.0.4664.45: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), **dynamically linked, interpreter `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`**, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=c44e075047fbfa647481929b2820890db74143ba, stripped

I confirmed with `readelf -l` the output of file. On my host machine `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` exists but on Alpine `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` does not exist. This is because the webdriver is compiled as GNU Libc but Alpine uses MUSL. We can still get it work, we just need to use Alpine's chrome web driver.

### Making `ng e2e` run under Alpine/MUSL

This method worked to worked chromium webdriver under Alpine.

1. Install necessary Alpine packages.

   ```
   apk add chromium chromium-chromedriver chromium-swiftshader
   ```
2. Set a `CHROMIUM_FLAGS` `CHROME_BIN` and `CHROME_PATH` in your image.

   ```
   CHROMIUM_FLAGS=--headless --disable-dev-shm-usage --disable-software-rasterizer
   CHROME_BIN=/usr/bin/chromium-browser
   CHROME_PATH=/usr/lib/chromium
   ```
3. In your `e2e/protractor.conf.js` make sure to include this stuff. Note you don't have to specify `--no-sandbox` if you have chrome running as a different user and you have a multi-user container.

   ```
   const path = require('path');

   exports.config = {
     chromeDriver: path.join(process.env.CHROME_PATH, 'chromedriver'),
     capabilities: {
       browserName: 'chrome',
       chromeOptions: {
         args: ["--no-sandbox"],
         binary: process.env.CHROME_BIN,
       }
     },
   ```

### Bad solution: `gcompat`

Official advice suggests installing `gcompat` this did not work and returned the following errors,

```
Error relocating <PATH> chromedriver_96.0.4664.45: __mbrlen: symbol not found
Error relocating <PATH>/chromedriver_96.0.4664.45: __close: symbol not found
Error relocating <PATH>/chromedriver_96.0.4664.45: random_r: symbol not found
Error relocating <PATH>/chromedriver_96.0.4664.45: initstate_r: symbol not found
```

It seems that gcompat is more of a [Work in Progress as of Dec 2021](https://git.adelielinux.org/adelie/gcompat/-/merge_requests/13)

Answer (score 0):

`ENOENT` is a classic symptom of a missing dynamic linker; see *e.g.* [Why does chroot get ENOENT on an existing file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/146059/86440)

If you want to run glibc-based binaries in your container, it’s best to use a glibc-based base image, rather than a musl-base one (like Alpine).

There are many base images which should meet your requirements, to actually recommend one I would need to know more about what those really are.